QGIS problem when combining label background
I need to create a QGIS project where, along a “line” geometry, there are point elements representing road signs. Each point element should be styled with the sign image (in raster or SVG format), accompanied by a panel indicating a distance. I have attached an example of a road sign for reference.
Each point element has an attribute called “label_km” that contains the distance label to be displayed below the sign symbol.
To implement the project, I considered the following options:
Symbolization without labels: using symbology to combine the road sign symbol with a rectangular ellipse as a background. However, with this approach, the symbols remain bound to the geometry, and leader lines cannot be used. For this reason, this option was discarded.
Using labels with background enabled: activating labels to position the sign image and the ellipse, allowing both repositioning and leader lines. This solution was implemented.
Issues Encountered
With option 2, the map view result is satisfactory.
However, in the print layout, changing the layout zoom (not the map zoom) distorts the combined symbol, and the PDF export does not accurately reflect what is shown in the map view.
How can I solve the issue described above and to implement the intended label?
I am attaching the QGIS project and the underlying data used.
Project Archive

to me it looks like a bug that the background elipse is changing its size in the layout while zooming even when size is fixed in mm or points or map units. May be you can try to use HTML labels, in the new 3.40 version images are supported within HTML labels: https://www.qgis.org/project/visual-changelogs/visualchangelog340/#feature-support-img-tags-in-html-label-text
